# It is possible to crawl all images by a hashtag on Instagram?

Tags: php, web-crawler, instagram, instagram-api

Iam building a social network website.

I want to crawl information of **ALL** images by a hashtag on Instagram by using Instagram API. ( I only store url link to instagram image, without store image on my server )

Is is possible ? Or Instagram API only response a limit number of recent images ?

Thanks all!

Comment: Note that the Instagram terms of service likely limit your abilities here, too.

Answer (score 1):

[When looking at the API docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/), it seems that the total amount of media on a certain hashtag can be looked up, but the actual media can only be found for recent posts.

So if you actually want to save all media, you might want to scrape all data every now and then. [You do have a limit on how many times you can scrape though](https://www.instagram.com/developer/limits/).

Answer (score 0):

Using API you can get all hashtag media, it will start with most recent posts, you have to paginate and can get call data.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

As of Oct 1, 2017, Instagram no longer gives permission for `public_content` scope that is required to access this data, if dont already have your app approved, you will not be able to use this API :(

Comment: There have any way to get public_content now?